# Explain effect of ES6 class constructor and arrow functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, module, ecmascript-6

I'm currently learning JS and ES6 in particular. I'm having trouble understanding why my code with class constructor and arrow functions doesn't work without a few changes.

Here is where I started, an ES6 module exporting this flux-like dispatcher object.

```
// RiotControl dispatcher formatted as ES6 module.
// https://github.com/jimsparkman/RiotControl

var dispatcher = {
  stores: [],
  addStore: function(store) {
    this.stores.push(store);
  }
};

['on','one','off','trigger'].forEach(function(api){
  dispatcher[api] = function() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    this.stores.forEach(function(el){
      el[api].apply(null, args);
    });
  };
});

export default dispatcher
```

I wanted to make a class out of this code and originally ended up with:

```
// RiotControl dispatcher formatted as ES6 class module.
// https://github.com/jimsparkman/RiotControl

export default class {
  constructor() {        
    this.stores = []    
    this.addStore = store => {
      this.stores.push(store);
    }

    ['on','one','off','trigger'].forEach(fn => {
      this[fn] = () => {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments)
        this.stores.forEach(function(el){
          el[fn].apply(null, args)
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

For reasons unknown to me, this doesn't work.

1. The first `.forEach(...)` results in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`, as if the array is not defined.
2. `var args = [].slice.call(arguments)` results in args being a zero length array instead of actually, umm, having the arguments.

To get the code working, I changed it to this:

```
// RiotControl dispatcher formatted as ES6 class module.
// https://github.com/jimsparkman/RiotControl

export default class {
  constructor() {        
    this.stores = []    
    this.addStore = store => {
      this.stores.push(store);
    }

    var api = ['on','one','off','trigger']
    api.forEach(fn => {
      this[fn] = function() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments)
        this.stores.forEach(function(el){
          el[fn].apply(null, args)
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Thus, the errors were fixed by

1. declaring an array and calling `.forEach` on that and
2. using a regular callback function instead of the arrow function.

Please explain why the `forEach` with an inline array fails and why slicing the arguments list fails from inside the arrow function.

Also, bonus question, why is `this` in ´this.stores.foreach` bound to my object instance and not e.g. the event that causes the function to be called?

Comment: Do you still get the errors if you use delimiters `;`? You seem to be allergic to them

Comment: Correct, a missing semicolon was the reason for error #1. I'm not allergic, but several libraries I've looked at seem to omit delimiters. I just need to learn the rules and adopt a convention to use or not use them. Using them seems safer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please explain why the `forEach` with an inline array fails and why slicing the arguments list fails from inside the arrow function.

The code is interpreted as follows:

```
this.addStore = store => { ... }['on','one','off','trigger'].forEach(...)
// which becomes
this.addStore = store => { ... }['trigger'].forEach(...)
```

I.e. you are trying to access the `trigger` property of a function, which of course does not exist. Use a semicolon after the function definition to explicitly terminate the assignment expression:

```
this.addStore = store => {
  this.stores.push(store);
};
['on','one','off','trigger'].forEach(...);
```

> Also, bonus question, why is this in `this.stores.foreach` bound to my object instance and not e.g. the event that causes the function to be called?

`this` is not bound here. What `this` refers to depends on how the function is called, which you shouldn't show.

---

> `var args = [].slice.call(arguments)` results in args being a zero length array instead of actually, umm, having the arguments.

In arrow functions, both `this` and `arguments` are lexically scoped. I.e. arrow functions don't have their own `arguments` object.

Comment: Thanks, excellent answer! Makes perfect sense now that you explained it.

Comment: If you could, please edit this typo in your answer: What `this` refers to depends on how the function is called, which you shouldn't [=> don't] show.